# What is the difference between Polymer paper-tabs and iron-selector?

Tags: polymer

I was looking at the source code for the header on the [Polymer website](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) so I could build a similar one for my app.

They use [iron-selector](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-selector) for the menu items.

But on their documentation page for [responsive-navigation-pattern](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/app-layout#responsive-navigation-pattern) they use [paper-tabs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs) for the same kind of header implementation with tabs.

What is the difference between `iron-selector` and `paper-tabs` and which one should I use if I want a similar header for my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<iron-selector>` element manages item selection and has no template or styling (i.e., it doesn't look like the top nav on Polymer's site out of the box). If you want a barebones control, where you could fine-tune the styling of the selected items yourself, this element would be ideal.

The `<paper-tabs>` element also manages item selection, but includes its own styling (which follows material design) and navigation controls to access the tabs out of view. If you prefer a responsive control that uses material design and other customizable styles, this might be a better choice.

The `<iron-selector>` on the main page of the Polymer site is styled similarly to the `<paper-tabs>` element's default style, and since that's the look you're after, I recommend `<paper-tabs>` mainly because it achieves your goal with less effort required.

Comment: @Diyarbakir No problem :)